# PictureBox Drag and Drop to MS Word

Tags: vb.net

I have created an app with a flowlayoutpanel of pictureboxes. I have implemented drag and drop based on the original code found here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4436369c-eae2-4994-bb64-3c51ada96f07/dragn-drop-from-a-picturebox-to-word?forum=vblanguage

which is, in turn, based on:

http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi/browse_thread/thread/197b47c39f8ad2c8/e2e4b88de9f83d3a

```
 Private Sub P_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles P.MouseDown
        ' see
        ' http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi/browse_thread/thread/197b47c39f8ad2c8/e2e4b88de9f83d3a
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream
        Dim ms2 As New MemoryStream
        Dim theformat As ImageFormat


        Dim pb = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)

        Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(pb.Tag)

        Select Case ext

            Case ".png"
                theformat = ImageFormat.Png
            Case ".jpg"
                theformat = ImageFormat.Jpeg
            Case ".gif"
                theformat = ImageFormat.Gif
            Case Else
                Return
        End Select



        pb.Image.Save(ms, theformat)
        pb.DoDragDrop(pb.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy)
        Dim bytes() As Byte = ms.GetBuffer
        ms2.Write(bytes, 14, CInt(ms.Length - 14))
        ms.Position = 0
        Dim obj As New DataObject
        obj.SetData("DeviceIndependentBitmap", ms2)
        pb.DoDragDrop(obj, DragDropEffects.Copy)
        ms.Close()
        ms2.Close()
    End Sub
```

The routine works splendidly dropping images into MS Excel 2013, however, I need to use it with MS Word. When I drag an image to Word, the cursor shows the proper Arrow-box-plus-sign cursor, but releasing the mouse button doesn't drop the image. Nor does it throw any sort of error.

I'm at a loss to troubleshoot this issue. I've been googling for fixes, but mainly find VB Form-to-VB Form solutions.

If you can point me along to figuring this out or suggest a code change, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: It does not make sense to call DoDragDrop() twice.  You'll only get the first one, the one you already know doesn't work.  So delete it.

Comment: Ah, that's right. That's most likely a careless cut and paste. Thanks!

Comment: The routine works fine with Excel. Taking one out will break it. The code is working with two memory streams. One to move the image out and one to drag it into the target.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work for me... You were saving as PNG/JPG/GIF, none of which are DIBs (or even bitmaps)

```
    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown

    ' see
    ' http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi/browse_thread/thread/197b47c39f8ad2c8/e2e4b88de9f83d3a
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream
    Dim ms2 As New MemoryStream


    Dim pb = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)

    pb.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp)
    pb.DoDragDrop(pb.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    Dim bytes() As Byte = ms.ToArray()
    ms2.Write(bytes, 14, CInt(ms.Length - 14))

    ms.Position = 0
    Dim obj As New DataObject
    obj.SetData("DeviceIndependentBitmap", ms2)
    pb.DoDragDrop(obj, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    ms.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: I started out with that and had issues trying to drag PNG images. That's why I added the select case for the other extensions.

Also, it does work just fine. I'm able to drag to Excel.

Comment: Don't use `ms.GetBuffer` here, it's quite "dangerous". Use `ms.ToArray()`.

Comment: @Jimi, the code works the same with ms.Array(). Can you tell why  ms.GetBuffer is dangerous? Thanks.

Comment: @Ring  The `MemoryStream` internal Buffer is resized when some data is *received*. Usually, the buffer is expanded in a pre-emptive manner: meaning, it could be set to the double of the data received (you can check this yourself, inspecting that value at debug-time). Thus, the Buffer size and the Content length don't match. The `MemoryStream.ToArray()` method returns just the data content of the Buffer, given the Content length (not the Buffer size). For a *finite* object as an Image, it won't compromise the object. But the exceeding bytes will be part of it anyway (appended to it).

Comment: @Jimi, thanks. I'll keep that in mind and add it to my notes of things to avoid!

This thing is making me pull out hair. I can't understand why it works for Excel and not for Word.

Comment: @Jimi, Good spot, I'm not sure why I put GetBuffer, because I don't usually use that. Updated the code